# Can python abstract base classes inherit from C extensions?

Tags: python, inheritance, gevent, abc, greenlets

It seems as if that when I have an abstract base class that inherits from gevent.Greenlet (which inherits from the C extension module greenlet: https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet) then classes that implement it do not raise any of the abc errors about unimplemented methods.

```
class ActorBase(gevent.Greenlet):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        print "foo"

class ActorBaseTest(ActorBase):
    def bar(self):
        print "bar"

abt = ActorBaseTest()  # no errors!
```

If I inherit from `object` it fails as expected:

```
class ActorBase(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        print "foo"

class ActorBaseTest(ActorBase):
    def bar(self):
        print "bar"

>>> abt = ActorBaseTest()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dw/.virtualenvs/prj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2827, in run_code
exec code_obj in self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns
  File "<ipython-input-6-d67a142e7297>", line 1, in <module>
    abt = ActorBaseTest()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class ActorBaseTest with abstract methods foo
```

What is the right way to implement this functionality?

Comment: In general, it should be OK. However, `gevent.Greenlet` may not be a new-style class, which could interfere with the ABC machinery.

Comment: Oops, you're right.  gevent.Greenlet inherits from a C extension module.  I'll edit question to ask what a good way to implement this use-case is.

Comment: Inheriting from a type implemented in C shouldn't be a problem, in general.  There must be something specific to the `greenlet.greenlet` class itself that's interfering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cause of your problem is that it's the [`object.__new__`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/bd71352e950f/Objects/typeobject.c#l3105) method that does the check for instantiation of an abstract class, and in this case `object.__new__` isn't being invoked:  `gevent.Greenlet` inherits from `greenlet.greenlet`, and `greenlet.greenlet` is a C extension type whose `__new__` implementation doesn't call `object.__new__` at any point (see the [`green_new`](https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet/blob/master/greenlet.c#L840) function in the `greenlet` C source).

You can see the same effect by subclassing some of the other builtin types that implement their own `__new__` method and don't refer back to `object.__new__` (the `float` type, for example).  The issue is not particular to C extension types, though: you can also replicate it with pure Python types.  Consider the code below:

```
import abc

class A(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        # self = object.__new__(cls)
        return 42

class B(A):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass

b = B()  # No exception.
```

The class `B` is correctly registered as an abstract class (internally, its `Py_TPFLAGS_IS_ABSTRACT` bit is set in the `tp_flags` field), but `object.__new__` is never called, so there's no error when `B` is instantiated.  However, if you uncomment the `self = object.__new__(cls)` method call in `A`, you'll see the expected error on instantiation.

As far as the 'right way' to implement this, unfortunately I think the right way is to fix the `greenlet` type so that its `__new__` method calls `object.__new__`. I guess you could add a `__new__` method to `ActorBase` that explicitly calls both the base class `__new__` *and* `object.__new__` (and throws away the result of the latter), but I'd consider that an ugly workaround rather than the 'right way'. (EDIT: And on top of that, it doesn't work.  I get `TypeError: object.__new__(ActorBase) is not safe, use greenlet.greenlet.__new__()` from the `object.__new__` call.)  I've opened an [issue](http://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet/issues/34) on the greenlet tracker.

---

EDIT: This problem seemed somewhat familiar, and I just did some digging into the [Enthought Traits](https://github.com/enthought/traits) source, which defines a `CHasTraits` class implemented in C which *does* play nicely with ABCs.  And its `__new__` method starts like this (comments are from the original source, not mine):

```
PyObject *
has_traits_new ( PyTypeObject * type, PyObject * args, PyObject * kwds ) {

    // Call PyBaseObject_Type.tp_new to do the actual construction.
    // This allows things like ABCMeta machinery to work correctly
    // which is implemented at the C level.
    has_traits_object * obj = (has_traits_object *) PyBaseObject_Type.tp_new(type, empty_tuple, empty_dict);
```

So perhaps the long-term solution is to persuade the `greenlet` folks to do something similar.

Comment: For anyone who comes along later, the issue @Mark Dickinson raised on the greenlet tracker led to greenlet implementing a fix.  The problem I posted about is now fixed for greenlets.