# Have C extension class inherit from Python class

Tags: python, python-c-api

I have a Python class `AbstractFoo` which uses `@abc.abstractmethod` to define 2 abstract methods.

For more performance the bulk of the work is implemented in C as a Python extension class `CFoo`, so what I wanted to do is to inherit that extension class from `AbstractFoo`.

However I haven't found a way to do this and went a different route: Implement it as a "normal" class in C and have a `class ConcreteFoo(AbstractFoo, CFoo)` which inherits from the abstract Python and the extension class.

However now the "protection" from the ABC didn't kick in: No error was thrown even when the methods were missing. I found a solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20440259/1930508 and added a new `new` method instead of `PyType_GenericNew` (ignore the ref counts of the empty_* parts for now):

```
static PyObject* CFoo_new(PyTypeObject* type, PyObject*, PyObject*)
{
    auto* empty_tuple(PyTuple_New(0));
    if (!empty_tuple)
        return nullptr;
    auto* empty_dict(PyDict_New());
    if (!empty_dict)
        return nullptr;
    return PyBaseObject_Type.tp_new(type, empty_tuple.get(), empty_dict.get());
}
```

But now the ABC check always triggers: `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class ConcreteFoo with abstract methods ...`
But checking `dir(ConcreteFoo)` shows the methods it complains about.

Is there a way to have an ABC-checked subclass of my `AbstractFoo` where the methods are implemented in C?

Edit: Some more code:

```
class AbstractFoo(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def register(self):
        pass
    # ...

#...

class ConcreteFoo(AbstractFoo, CFoo):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        AbstractFoo.__init__(self)
        CFoo.__init__(self, arg)
```

Comment: I think `__abstractmethods__` is set on the creation of the type by `ABCMeta`. Therefore, you need to ensure that this metaclass is called when you define the type `ConcreteFoo`, not `PyType_Type`. Unfortunately you don't show this bit of code...

Comment: I'm not sure what code you mean. The not shown code is pretty much the basic boilerplate code you use. I added the definition of `ConcreteFoo` and the important part of `AbstractFoo` above

Comment: Ah - I misunderstood slightly and thought that you were declaring `ConcreteFoo` in C (e.g. with `PyObject_Call(PyType_Type,...`) That does make things clearer

Comment: `register` is a dangerous choice for an abstract method name, because it conflicts with [`abc`'s own use of the name `register`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make `CFoo` the first base class. This has little to do with the C-API and applies to a pure Python version too: if you define

```
class CFoo:
    def register(self):
        return "CFoo.register"
```

then

```
class ConcreteFoo(AbstractFoo, CFoo):
```

fails, but

```
class ConcreteFoo(CFoo, AbstractFoo):
```

works.

This makes sense in terms of the `__mro__` and you can test this by making `register` not be an abstract method. You'll find that the method of the first base class in used in preference. When the first base class is `AbstractFoo` this *is* an abstract method that's being found first, so it fails.

Comment: This is correct and works, thanks. I find this counter-intuitive as I'd expect inheritance work from lft to right. For completeness: Do you happen to have a link to the official documentation?

Comment: Maybe https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/ (although it obviously gets quite detailed quite quickly). Maybe the way to think about it is that all the methods in all the base classes still exist and it searches from left to right to find a suitable method (and not "methods get overridden by new base classes being added", which I think is what you're assuming)